# How to catch all of Errors in node application

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have an application written in node - puppeteer.
I have one main function, but this function is built from another function, and actually, I do not know where can be an eroror, so I want to catch all of the errors that are in this function and restart the whole application but how can I do this?

example:
I was trying with try...catch and process.on, but these ways not work :/

```
const init = async () => {
    const { page, browser } = await initPage();
    logo();
    connectToDb();
    await login(page, process.env.USERNAME, process.env.PASSWORD);
    await retwitt(page);

    process.on('uncaughtException', async () => {
        baseLog("Retwiter catched an error, retwiter will be started again.");
        await browser.close();
        init();
    });
};
```

I want to catch error from the retwitt() function or just from entire application.

```
const retwitt = async (page) => {
    await page.goto(URLwithLangQuery('/home'));
    await delay(calcMinsToMs(waitMinsAfterGoToHome));

    const twittToShareLink = URLwithLangQuery(await twittSelector(page));
    baseLog("Selected twitt to share: ", twittToShareLink);
    if (!await wasTwittShared(twittToShareLink)) {
        await page.goto(twittToShareLink);
        await clickRetwittButton(page);
        await confirmRetwitt(page, twittToShareLink);    
        await delay(calcMinsToMs(waitMinsAfterRetwitt));
        await retwitt(page);
    } else {
        actionLog("Twitt was already shared.")
        await delay(calcMinsToMs(waitMinsAfterSelectingAlreadyRetwittedPost));
        await retwitt(page);
    }
};
```

Comment: You catch errors from `await` with `try/catch` around it.  You can put a single `try/catch` around multiple `await` statements.   You should not be relying on `process.on('uncaughtException', ...)` the way you show because the application is in an unstable state at that point for anything other than cleanup before shutdown.

Comment: But wrapping each method with try catch is not a good practice I think

Comment: Nowhere did I say you wrap every method with `try/catch`.  You can put ONE `try/catch` inside of `retwitt()` or `init()` with all the `await` statements inside of it and that will catch any promise rejection from any of the `await` statements you have in that function.'

Comment: But each await methods inside retwitt are build with other functions, that's why I wanted to create something that let me catch all of the errors in the application in one place in code

Answer (score 0):

You can catch rejections from multiple `await` statement with one `try/catch` and since rejections propagate upwards when using `await`, you can catch them at a higher level too like this:

```
const init = async () => {
    // let this one throw back to the caller because if you can't initPage()
    // there's nothing else to really do here
    const { page, browser } = await initPage();     

    // catch the rest locally and restart upon error
    try {
        logo();
        connectToDb();
        await login(page, process.env.USERNAME, process.env.PASSWORD);
        await retwitt(page);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        browser.close().then(init, init);
    }
};
```

So, this will catch any rejections in `login()` or `retwitt()` regardless of where they happen in those functions (assuming they return a promise that would be rejected upon error).

I chose not to catch the error from `initPage()` because if you can't initialize the page, there's really nothing else to do so the caller should probably handler that case.  You could catch it locally and just `return` (or do something else) if that's the preferred behavior.

---

FYI, it's generally not advisable to automatically retry immediately upon error like your original code was trying to do (and like this code does to follow that direction).  In generally, you would insert a slight delay before the next retry and you'd implement a retry counter and stop retrying after a certain number of tries.  Otherwise, any persistent error will just create a forever loop that will likely just sap all your CPU and never stop running.

To implement both a retryCntr and a short delay, you could do this:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}


const init = async () => {
    let maxRetries = 5;

    function again() {
        return delay(500).then(run);
    }
    
    async function run() {
        --maxRetries;
        if (maxRetries < 0) {
            throw new Error("Exceeded max number of retries");
        }

        // let this one throw back to the caller because if you can't initPage()
        // there's nothing else to really do here
        const { page, browser } = await initPage();     

        // catch the rest locally and restart upon error
        try {
            logo();
            connectToDb();
            await login(page, process.env.USERNAME, process.env.PASSWORD);
            await retwitt(page);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            browser.close().then(again, again);
        }
    }

    return run();
};
```